# Konva Textpath: how does it calculate x and y position

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

## EDIT: there was a bug in the code, so this question is not valid.

I'm trying hard to get Konva.textpath to work. The problem is that the x & y point seems completely random.

There are 3 examples. The green box is placed on the same x/y as the textpath, the red line is the path and all paths (in data) starts at 0,0.

### Example 1:

[image: Path 1]

Path: `M0,0c138.1,0,250,111.9,250,250S138.1,500,0,500s-250-111.9-250-250S-138.1,0,0,0`

### Example 2:

[image: Path 1 with text overflow]
Same path, but with text overflowing. It's not easy to see, but the start of the path is moved about 18px

### Example 3:

[image]
Path `M0,0c138.1,0,250,111.9,250,250S138.1,500,0,500s-250-111.9-250-250S-138.1,0,0,0`

**I fail to see any logic to the placement.** The expected result would be that x & y of the text should be the start of the text.
These are not some hard to find examples. Every path I try behaves the same.

Thankful for an explanation.

Comment: Can you post your exact path code for each case please. I am trying to repro the issue and want to make it a fair match.

Comment: Not an answer, just another  question. How did you calculate svg path ?

Comment: @DavitMkrtchyan Do you mean how to get a svg path? The easiest way is to draw a path in any graphics editor, save file as svg and open svg file in a text editor or IDE.
(Edit: You can actually write your own svg paths, the syntax is easy, but it's insanely hard to visualize)

Comment: @Krillko thanks, but I thought you got path programmatically, calculating text length and angles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are saying that the if you set the co-ords of the small green rectangle to the same (x,y) as the first point in the path then the position does not match the start of the path.

Here is a snippet of code with which I am trying to confirm your result but for me the pink rectangle is placed where it should be.

What other code do you have? Maybe an offset is being applied, or maybe a group ? It seems unlikely that your path starts at stage(0,0) because that would see some clipping of the letter 'L' which would draw partially off the stage.

Conclusion: more info required to repro the issue, or double check your code?

```js
// Set up the canvas / stage
var stage = new Konva.Stage({container: 'container1', width: 600, height: 300});

// Add a layer for line
var layer = new Konva.Layer({draggable: false});
stage.add(layer);

// draw a path.
    var path = new Konva.Path({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      stroke: 'cyan'
    });
layer.add(path)



var dot = new Konva.Rect({x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20, fill: 'magenta' });
layer.add(dot);


var path = new Konva.Path({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  stroke: 'cyan'
})
layer.add(path);


var textpath = new Konva.TextPath({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 32,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  text: 'Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum'
});

layer.add(textpath);
    
stage.draw()

$('#path1').on('click', function(){
var data = "M20,20c138.1,0,250,111.9,250,250S138.1,500,0,500s-250-111.9-250-250S-138.1,0,0,0";
textpath.setData(data);
path.setData(data);
var pt = path.getPointAtLength(0);
dot.position({x: pt.x, y: pt.y});
layer.draw();
})


$('#path2').on('click', function(){
var data = "M 120 20 a 100 100 0 1 0 0.00001 0";
textpath.setData(data);
path.setData(data);
var pt = path.getPointAtLength(0);
dot.position({x: pt.x, y: pt.y});
layer.draw();
})



$('#path3').on('click', function(){
var data = "M200 200 S 200.5 200 201.1 200.2 201.5 200.4 202 200.7 202.4 201.1 202.8 201.5 203.1 202.1 203.3 202.7 203.5 203.3 203.6 204 203.5 204.7 203.4 205.4 203.2 206.1 202.9 206.9 202.5 207.6 201.9 208.3 201.3 209 200.6 209.6 199.8 210.1 198.9 210.6 197.9 211 196.8 211.3 195.7 211.5 194.6 211.6 193.3 211.5 192.1 211.4 190.8 211.1 189.6 210.7 188.3 210.1 187.1 209.4 185.9 208.6 184.7 207.6 183.6 206.5 182.6 205.2 181.7 203.9 181 202.4 180.3 200.8 179.8 199.2 179.4 197.4 179.1 195.6 179.1 193.7 179.2 191.8 179.5 189.8 179.9 187.8 180.6 185.9 181.4 184 182.5 182.1 183.7 180.3 185.1 178.5 186.7 176.9 188.4 175.4 190.3 174 192.4 172.8 194.6 171.7 196.9 170.8 199.4 170.1 201.9 169.7 204.5 169.4 207.2 169.4 209.9 169.6 212.6 170 215.3 170.7 218 171.6 220.6 172.8 223.2 174.2 225.7 175.9 228 177.8 230.2 179.9 232.2 182.3 234.1 184.8 235.8 187.5 237.2 190.5 238.4 193.5 239.3 196.7 240 200 240.4 203.4 240.5 206.8 240.3 210.3 239.8 213.9 239 217.4 237.9 220.8 236.4 224.2 234.7 227.5 232.7 230.7 230.3 233.7 227.7 236.5 224.9 239.2 221.7 241.6 218.4 243.8 214.8 245.7 211.1 247.3 207.2 248.5 203.1 249.5 199 250.1 194.7 250.4 190.4 250.3 186.1 249.8 181.8 249 177.5 247.8 173.3 246.2 169.3 244.2 165.3 241.9 161.6 239.2 158 236.2 154.7 232.9 151.6 229.3 148.9 225.4 146.4 221.2 144.3 216.8 142.6 212.2 141.3 207.4 140.3 202.5 139.8 197.5 139.7 192.4 140 187.2 140.8 182.1 142 177 143.6 172 145.7 167.1 148.2 162.4 151.1 157.8 154.5 153.5 158.2 149.5 162.3 145.7 166.7 142.3 171.4 139.2 176.4 136.5 181.6 134.2 187.1 132.4 192.8 131 198.5 130.1 204.4 129.7 210.4 129.8 216.3 130.4 222.2 131.5 228.1 133.1 233.9 135.2 239.4 137.9 244.8 141 250 144.5 254.8 148.5 259.4 153 263.5 157.8 267.3 163 270.6 168.5 273.5 174.4 275.9 180.5 277.8 186.8 279.2 193.4 280 200 280.3 206.7 279.9 213.5 279 220.3 277.6 227 275.5 233.6 272.9 240.1 269.7 246.3 266 252.3 261.8 258 257.1 263.4 251.9 268.4 246.3 272.9 240.3 277 233.9 280.6 227.2 283.7 220.2 286.2 213 288.1 205.6 289.4 198.1 290.1 190.5 290.2 182.9 289.6 175.3 288.4 167.8 286.5 160.5 284 153.3 280.8 146.4 277.1 139.8 272.7 133.6 267.8 127.7 262.4 122.3 256.4 117.4 250 113.1 243.2 109.3 235.9 106.1 228.4 103.5 220.5 101.6 212.4 100.4 204.2 99.8 195.8 100 187.4 100.9 178.9 102.5 170.6 104.8 162.3 107.8 154.2 111.5 146.4 115.9 138.9 120.9 131.7 126.5 124.9 132.7 118.6 139.4 112.8 146.7 107.6 154.4 103 162.4 99 170.9 95.7 179.6 93.1 188.6 91.3 197.7 90.2 206.9 89.8 216.2 90.3 225.5 91.5 234.6 93.5 243.6 96.3 252.4 99.8 260.9 104.1 269 109.1 276.7 114.8 284 121.1 290.7 128.1 296.8 135.7 302.4 143.7 307.2 152.3 311.3 161.2 314.7 170.6 317.3 180.2 319 190 320 200 320.1 210.1 319.4 220.2 317.8 230.2 315.3 240.2 312.1 249.9 308 259.4 303.1 268.5 297.4 277.2 291 285.4 283.9 293.1 276.1 300.3 267.7 306.7 258.8 312.5 249.4 317.5 239.6 321.7 229.4 325.1 218.9 327.7 208.1 329.3 197.3 330.1 186.3 330 175.4 328.9 164.6 326.9 153.9 324 143.5 320.2 133.3 315.5 123.6 309.9 114.3 303.6 105.6 296.4 97.5 288.5 90 279.9 83.2 270.7 77.2 260.9 72.1 250.7 67.8 239.9 64.4 228.8 61.9 217.4 60.4 205.9 59.9 194.1 60.3 182.4 61.8 170.6 64.2 159 67.6 147.6 72 136.4 77.3 125.7 83.5 115.4 90.6 105.6 98.5 96.4 107.2 87.8 116.6 80 126.7 73 137.3 66.8 148.5 61.5 160.1 57.2 172.1 53.8 184.4 51.5 196.9 50.2 209.4 49.9 222 50.7 234.6 52.5 247 55.4 259.1 59.4 270.9 64.4 282.3 70.3 293.2 77.2 303.5 85.1 313.1 93.8 322 103.3 330.2 113.5 337.4 124.5 343.7 136 349.1 148.1 353.4 160.6 356.7 173.5 358.9 186.7 358.9 186.7";
textpath.setData(data);
path.setData(data);
var pt = path.getPointAtLength(0);
dot.position({x: pt.x, y: pt.y});
layer.draw();
})
$('#path1').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/2.5.1/konva.min.js"></script>
<div  >  
<button id='path1'>Path 1</button>
<button id='path2'>Path 2</button>
<button id='path3'>Path 3</button>
</div>
<div id='container1' style="width: 300px, height: 200px; background-color: silver; margin:10px;padding:10px;"></div>
<div id='img'></div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for giving it a try. I've did some more test myself but it seems like the error is in another part of my code that recalculates the offset to rotate around center of konva object. It's possibly a bug there in my code, and it hasn't been discovered because it never encountered Textpath before.

Comment: That's life in coding. If it helps, there's a function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277253/rotating-around-a-point-offset-function-moves-the-shape) for changing the offset but NOT the position of a Konvajs group.

Comment: So, I found the problem, another method calculated the centerpoint and changed the offset. It's been there forever so I forgot about it, it works on text, shape, group, images etc, but not on textpath.